# What's the best way to store files on a remote host as they are created and remove the originals?

Tags: bash, backup, rsync, scp, data-storage

**Basically I want to move files to another server on creation preserving the directory structure. I have a solution put it lacks elegance.** Also I feel like I'm missing the obvious answer, so thanks in advance for your help and I totally understand if this bores you.

## The situation

I have server with limited disk space (let's call it 'Tiny') and a storage server. Tiny creates files every once in a while. I want to store them automatically on the storage server and remove the originals when it's safe. I have to retain the directory structure of tiny. I don't know in advance how the dir structure looks like. That is, all files are created in the directory `/some/dir/` but sudirectories of this are created on the fly. They should be sotred in `/other/fold/` on the storege server preserving the substcrutre under `/some/dir`. E.g:

`/some/dir/bla/foo/bar/snap_001a` on tiny ---> becomes `/other/fold/bla/foo/bar/snap_001a` on the storage server. They are all called `snap_xxxx` wgere xxxx is a four letter alphanumeric string.

## My old solution

Now I was thinking to loop over files and `scp` them. Once scp is finished and returns without error the files on tiny are removed with `rm`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is invoked by a cronjob ever once in a while.

files=$(find /some/dir/ -name snap_*)

IFS='
'
for current in $files; do
   name=$(basename $current)             # Get base name (i.e. strip directory)
   dir=$(dirname $current)               # Get the directory name of the curent file on tiny
   dir=${dir/\/some\/dir/\/other\/fold}  # Replace the directory root on tiny with the root on the storage server
   ssh -i keyfile myuser@storage.server.net \
     mkidir -p $dir                      # create the directory on the storage server and all parents if needed
   scp -i keyfile $current myuser@storage.server.net:$dir$name \
     && rm $current                      # remove files on success
done
```

This however **strikes me as unnecssarily complicated** and maybe **error prone**. I thought of `rsync` but when coping single files, there is no option to create a directory and it's parents if they don't exist. Does anyone have an idea, **better than** mine?

## What I ended up using after this thread

```
rsync -av --remove-sent-files --prune-empty-dirs          \
      -e 'ssh -i /full/path/to/keyfile'                   \
      --include="*/" --include="snap_*" --exclude="*"     \
      /some/dir/ myuser@storage.server.com:/other/fold/
```

More recent versions then the one I was using take `--remove-source-files` instead of `--remove-sent-files`. The former being more of a telling name in that it's clearer what files are deleted. Also `--dry-run` is a good option to test your parameters BEFORE actually using rsync.

Thanks to Alex Howansky for the solution and to Douglas Leeder for caring!

Comment: Don't rsync single files, rsync the root of your tree. it will figure out what's changed, only copy the new stuff, and will create all the subdirs automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's more complicated thatn that: How do I tell rsync just to copy the `snap_xxxx` files? How do I change the direcotry root? How do I delete the originals on Tiny after transfer to the storage server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I tell rsync just to copy the snap_xxxx files?

See the --include option.

> How do I change the direcotry root?

Just specify it on the command line.

```
rsync [options] source_dir dest_host:dest_dir
```

> How do I delete the originals on Tiny after transfer to the storage server?

See the --remove-source-files option.

Comment: I think you mean `--remove-source-files` ?

Comment: Whoa, weird. --remove-sent-files works fine but is not documented. Maybe it's an old option that got renamed but left in for backward compatibility? I'll update the answer in any case.

Comment: Reading the changelog, looks like it was deprecated in 2.6.9, but it's still functional.

Comment: Thank alot. Thought I was being stupid. So just to be sure: `rsync -a -e 'ssh -i keyfile' --remove-source-files --include "snap_*" /some/dir/ myuser@storage.server.net:/other/fold/` would do the trick, just include the `snap_xxx` files (and no others), remove them from the host on successful transfer and create non existing sub-directories of `/some/dir` within `/other/fold/` or do you see any mistakes?

Comment: That looks good. Also see --verbose and --dry-run for testing.

Comment: I think you need to say `--include='*/' --include='snap_*' --exclude='*' --prune-empty-dirs` (include folders, snap_* files, and exclude everything else, as well as directories that turn out not to have snap_* files in them).

Comment: @con-f-use Also don't include the final / on the destination, then the directories will be used correctly.

Comment: I had to include the final `/`. `--dry-run` was a good tipp. Sorry for bothering you guy, but rsync is really a huge tool to deal with especially if you never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
touch /tmp/start
rsync -va /some/dir/ /other/fold
find /some/dir -type f -not -newer /tmp/start | xargs rm
```